# Intel pin tool 3.5 Building Manual Examples

Tags: intel-pin

I am trying to run Manual Examples of Intel pin tool kit 3.5 in x64 architecture using Ubuntu...
but i am unable to build and got errors like

```
make[1]:Entering directory '/home/desktop/source/tools/ManualExamples' make libs
make[1]:Entering directory '/home/desktop/source/tools/ManualExamples'
make[1]:Nothing to be done for libs
```

i tried run these samples through command 
$ cd source/tools/ManualExamples
$ make inscount0.test TARGET=intel64